# Time based report from a large table with many update per day

Tags: postgresql

We have a relatively large table (around 10 million rows). This table has a `date_updated` column that we update every time a row is changed (every day around `4 million rows` are updated).

we have a couple of problems with this table:

1. table size:
   in a working cluster table size is `122GB` but after refreshing data (backup using pgdump and then restore) table size shrinks to `20GB`.
2. number of updated rows per day report:
   the queries takes so long to complete even after addition of suitable index (around `700s`) we checked the query planner output and are sure that the index is used (Index Only Scan)

we suspect that both of this problems are due to many table update but are not sure!

BTW, We use a postgresql cluster with two nodes (one master and one replica) the replica node is used for some report queries.

EDIT 1 table structure:

```
|               NAME           | TYPE                     | Nullable             |
-------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------
 id                            | integer                  |           | not null |   
 english_name                  | character varying(500)   |           | not null |
 image_url                     | character varying(1000)  |           | not null |
 category                      | character varying(200)   |           | not null |
 category_hierarchy            | text                     |           | not null |
 price                         | integer                  |           | not null |
 availability                  | boolean                  |           | not null |
 spec                          | text                     |           | not null |
 product_id                    | character varying(1000)  |           | not null |
 page_url                      | character varying(1000)  |           | not null |
 was_accessible                | boolean                  |           | not null |
 date_added                    | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 date_updated                  | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 random_key                    | character varying(50)    |           | not null |
 shop_id                       | integer                  |           | not null |
 base_product_id               | integer                  |           |          |
 analyzed_name                 | character varying(500)   |           | not null |
 clustering_meta               | hstore                   |           |          |
 date_specilized               | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 is_special_offer              | boolean                  |           | not null |
 manual_order_in_offer         | integer                  |           | not null |
 price_before_offer            | integer                  |           |          |
 offer_score                   | double precision         |           | not null |
 guarantee                     | character varying(500)   |           | not null |
 is_deleted                    | boolean                  |           | not null |
 priceable_relation_id         | integer                  |           |          |
 date_sent_for_update          | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 variation                     | jsonb                    |           |          |
 update_error                  | jsonb                    |           |          |
 last_date_available           | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 is_active                     | boolean                  |           | not null |
 feature_extractor_description | character varying(500)   |           | not null |
```

Index:

```
"webservice_productpage_update_report" btree (was_accessible, date_updated, shop_id, id) WHERE is_deleted = false AND is_active = true
```

auto vaccum related settings:

```
database=> SELECT name,setting,unit,reset_val from pg_settings where category like 'Autovacuum';
                name                 |  setting  | unit | reset_val
-------------------------------------+-----------+------+-----------
 autovacuum                          | on        |      | on
 autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor     | 0.1       |      | 0.1
 autovacuum_analyze_threshold        | 50        |      | 50
 autovacuum_freeze_max_age           | 200000000 |      | 200000000
 autovacuum_max_workers              | 3         |      | 3
 autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age | 400000000 |      | 400000000
 autovacuum_naptime                  | 60        | s    | 60
 autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay        | 20        | ms   | 20
 autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit        | -1        |      | -1
 autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor      | 0.2       |      | 0.2
 autovacuum_vacuum_threshold         | 50        |      | 50
```

vaccum metrics:

```
database=> SELECT relname, n_dead_tup, last_vacuum, last_autovacuum FROM pg_stat_user_tables where relname='webservice_productpage';
        relname         | n_dead_tup |          last_vacuum          |        last_autovacuum
------------------------+------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------
 webservice_productpage |   15021730 | 2020-01-20 20:46:59.105846+00 | 2020-02-02 05:06:44.169149+00
```

Comment: what type are you using for date_updated and what index type? Please show structure of the table.

Comment: Can you share your autovacuum settings?  Are there any long running transactions that would prevent autovacuum from doing it's job?

Comment: i double checked there is no long running transaction. @Jeremy

Comment: How are you determining the table sizes?  Is that counting just the table itself, or also the associated indexes and TOAST table?

Comment: i use `pg_total_relation_size`, which sums total disk space used by the table including indexes and toasted data @jjanes

Comment: Could you monitor the tabe size separately from the index sizes as well?  It can be important to know which is bloated, the table or the index.  If you change it now, of course it could be a while before you have the acquired sufficient new data about it.